# Scala Parse floating point numbers with StandardTokenParsers

Tags: parsing, scala

This is a grammar for a System of first order ODEs:

```
system ::= equation { equation }

equation ::= variable "=" (arithExpr | param) "\n"

variable ::= algebraicVar | stateVar

algrebraicVar ::= identifier

stateVar ::= algebraicVar'

arithExpr ::= term { "+" term | "-" term }

term ::= factor { "*" factor | "/" factor }

factor ::= algebraicVar
          | powerExpr
          | floatingPointNumber
          | functionCall
          | "(" arithExpr ")"

powerExpr ::= arithExpr {"^" arithExpr}
```

Notes:

- An identifier should be a valid Scala Identifier.
- A stateVar is an algebraicVar followed by one apostrophe (x' denotes the first derivative of x --with respect to time--)
- I haven't coded anything for a `functionCall` but I mean something like `Cos[Omega]`

This is what I have already

```
package tests

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.StdLexical
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical.StandardTokenParsers
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers
import token._

object Parser1 extends StandardTokenParsers {

  lexical.delimiters ++= List("(", ")", "=", "+", "-", "*", "/", "\n")
  lexical.reserved ++= List(
    "Log", "Ln", "Exp",
    "Sin", "Cos", "Tan",
    "Cot", "Sec", "Csc",
    "Sqrt", "Param", "'")

  def system: Parser[Any] = repsep(equation, "\n")
  def equation: Parser[Any] = variable ~ "=" ~ ("Param" | arithExpr )
  def variable: Parser[Any] = stateVar | algebraicVar
  def algebraicVar: Parser[Any] = ident
  def stateVar: Parser[Any] = algebraicVar ~ "\'"
  def arithExpr: Parser[Any] = term ~ rep("+" ~ term | "-" ~ term)
  def term: Parser[Any] = factor ~ rep("*" ~ factor | "/" ~ factor)
  def factor: Parser[Any] = algebraicVar | floatingPointNumber | "(" ~ arithExpr ~ ")"
  def powerExpr: Parser[Any] = arithExpr ~ rep("^" ~ arithExpr)


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val code = "x1 = 2.5 * x2"
    equation(new lexical.Scanner(code)) match {
      case Success(msg, _) => println(msg)
      case Failure(msg, _) => println(msg)
      case Error(msg, _) => println(msg)
    }
  }
}
```

However this line doesn't work:

```
def factor: Parser[Any] = algebraicVar | floatingPointNumber | "(" ~ arithExpr ~ ")"
```

Because I haven't defined what's a `floatingPointNumber`. First I tried to mix in JavaTokenParsers but then I get conflicting definitions. The reason I'm trying to use StandardTokenParsers instead of JavaTokenParsers is to use  able to use a set of predefined Keywords with

```
lexical.reserved ++= List(
    "Log", "Ln", "Exp",
    "Sin", "Cos", "Tan",
    "Cot", "Sec", "Csc",
    "Sqrt", "Param", "'")
```

I asked this on the Scala-user mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scala-user/KXlfGauGR9Q) but I haven't received enough replies. Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Given that mixing in `JavaTokenParsers` doesn't work, you might try mixing in `RegexParsers` instead and copying just the definition of `floatingPointNumber` from the source for `JavaTokenParsers`.

That definition, at least in [this version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/JavaTokenParsers.scala#L1) is simply a regex:

```
  def floatingPointNumber: Parser[String] =
    """-?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?[fFdD]?""".r
```

Comment: `object DynamicalSystemParser extends StandardTokenParsers with RegexParsers` gives the following error:   
overriding type Elem in trait TokenParsers, which equals tests.Parser1.lexical.Token;  
type Elem in trait RegexParsers, which equals Char needs `override' modifier.  

Mixing JavaTokenParsers gives similar errors.

Comment: Ah well, guess you really can't mix these hierarchies much.

Comment: I have some progress (haven't finished yet). Please check the attached pdf parsingODEs.pdf at (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scala-user/KXlfGauGR9Q)